# Communication between Android device and Flex via BlazeDS feasible?

Tags: android, communication, blazeds

I'm currently looking for a good method for communication between one or multiple Google Android devices (smartphones) and an Adobe Flex frontend on a pc.

Requirements:

- Call functions on the other side (Flex to Android and vice versa)
- Send real time messages like changing sensor data from device to Flex

I stumbled upon BlazeDS and I'm wondering if it fits my needs and 
how it can be used for communication between participating parties.

What would be the best way to do methocd invocation on the remote site and sending real time data? Would therefore the messaging service be suitable (which would be my guess) or can i somehow use RPC/Remote Objects? T
he Java AMF Client could be used on the Android device.

I was thinking about sending messages to the server and the server could forward messages to the clients which translate them into function calls.

RPC is only ok for invoking a method call on the server but not calling a method on the client right?

Still not sure how to set this up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need communication between native Android code and Flex code on an Android device (an AIR app).  The only way to do that is through native integration.  Here is an blog post I wrote on how to do that:
http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Very cool stuff! But the Flex code will not be on the device! I need a communication between android app on the smartphone and a flex app on some a pc and still not sure which technology will do this best.

Comment: I see.  You can use BlazeDS Messaging to send messages from one Flex app to another Flex app through a server.  But in your case your Android app would have to also be built with Flex.

Comment: I saw there is an AMF Java Client but it's not very sophisticated. Anyway, i will play around with the Flex on Android approach to see how it works out and have a look at your great explanation on extending air for android to get the rest of the job done.

Thanks James!